# Angular js ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add form validation using JavaScript. When I add

```
 document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("ng-click", "insertData()");
```

to `validateForm` function, it does not work after I press the button.

When I move that line out of `validateForm` function it works, but does not perform form validation.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
   <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller = "controller">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="divID"> </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10  col-md-offset-1 ">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span> 
                            <input class="form-control" id = "k" placeholder="Name" ng-model = "username" name="user_name" type="text" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="NIC" ng-model = "nic" name="NIC" type="text" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"> @</span>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model = "Email" name="email" type="email" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model = "password" name="Password" type="password" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Confierm Password" ng-model = "Conf_password" name="Conf_password" type="password" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" id = 'one' onclick="validateForm()"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Sign Up">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
  <Script>
     function validateForm() 
       {
       var x = document.getElementById("k").value;
       if (x == "") 
         {
         document.getElementById("k").setAttribute("placeholder", "Insert Name");
         }
         else
         {
           //document.getElementById("one").removeAttribute("onclick");
           document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("ng-click", "insertData()");
          } 
       }
      // when add this part here code working fine ---- document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("ng-click", "insertData()");        

     var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
     app.controller("controller",function($scope,$http){
     $scope.insertData = function()
        {
         $http.post(
        "Signup.php",
        {'username':$scope.username,'nic':$scope.nic,'email':$scope.Email,'password':$scope.password,'Conf_password':$scope.Conf_password }

    ).then(function(data){

     var result = angular.toJson(data.data);
     var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
     if(result.replace(/^"|"$/g, '') == 1)
       {
       myEl.replaceWith("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade in'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>Success!</strong>You have sucessfully registerd. Please login</div>"); 
       }
     else
        {
         myEl.replaceWith(result.replace(/^"|"$/g, '')); 
         }
      $scope.username = null;
    });
  }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what you are trying to do is not how angularjs works; i suggest you to read [angularjs form documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), especially the *Binding to form and control state* chapter.
Your code seems a clash between jquery and angularjs, i suggest to you to re read [angularjs phonecat tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) or, even better, to try the new version of angular

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Angular that you've added an attribute, otherwise it doesn't work. When adding an attribute to your template file, Angular knows, but when adding it by `setAttribute()`, Angular has no idea.

---

In your controller, add the following two dependencies:

```
app.controller("controller", function($compile, $document, $scope, $http) {
    // 
});
```

Now, after adding the attribute to the element, you need to re-compile it:

```
$document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("ng-click", "insertData()"); 

// Try this:
$compile($document.getElementById("one"));

// If it doesn't work, or gives an error, try this:
$compile($document.getElementById("one"))($scope);
```

**Note: I use $document, not document**

[Documentation for $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage)

---

*Note: I cannot really test if this works for your code, but it should at least point you in the right direction. Your problem is that Angular doesn't know you added the attribute.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.. after adding ng click
where should i place this $compile($document.getElementById("one")) ?

Comment: In your controller, because it can execute Angular code. But, make sure, it runs *after* you added the element.

Comment: Yes i understood ...   I should add it in angular code but i can't find which place where i should place it in anguler part?

Comment: Try the bottom of your controller.

Comment: i add 
  $document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("ng-click", "insertData()");  to my validateForm()  function and  both of

 $compile($document.getElementById("one"))($scope); 

tried but it's not working and show  "TypeError: $document.getElementById is not a function" error

Comment: Hm. I actually think you need to redefine your logic, instead of fixing this. Why are you trying to add an attribute through `document.getElementById("one").setAttribute()`, instead of just adding it in your template?